# input() differs from ipython 2.7 to jupyter

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

Using jupyter 3.0.0-f75fda4 server

By the way: is Jupyter == "R" ?

I had some code yesterday that used the input function like:

```
var = input("Input LineA (x1,y1,x2,y2) ")
print var[0],var[1],var[2],var[3]
lineA = ((float(var[0]), float(var[1])), (float(var[2]), float(var[3])))
print lineA
```

resulting in the following output:

```
Input LineA (x1,y1,x2,y2) 10,10,0,0
10 10 0 0
((10.0, 10.0), (0.0, 0.0))
```

Now I cut&pasted the code into a jupyter notebook and the result is this:

```
Input LineA (x1,y1,x2,y2) 10,10,0,0
1 0 , 1
```

resulting then in all sorts of consequences for the subsequent code.

Comment: The first output was produced by a `python2` interpreter, the second by a `python3` interpreter. Regarding your question: you cannot compare `jupyter` with `R`. `jupyter` is a language agnostic framework for notebooks. `R` is a programming language.

Comment: And what does it mean towards fixing the problem? I need to stay with Python 3 in this particular case or maybe in the future.But in what relation is R to Jupyter? I see it mentioned solely in conjunction with jupyter or at least it seems to me.

Comment: Not sure what you would like to hear here. If you want to use python3, you have to write python3 compatible code. This has nothing to do with jupyter. `I see it mentioned solely in conjunction with jupyter`. R is heavily used by statisticians. I guess >99% of people using `R` have never heard of `jupyter` before.

Comment: In Python 3, `input()` will return a string, so `input[0]` is the first character. You can `eval()` the result if you want it to behave like Python 2 `input()`, or parse it yourself. For this case, you might be able to use [ast.literal_eval()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval), which is a safer, more restrictive version of eval().